# Movie/Book {by/from/of}

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is the best way to say that a movie is directed by someone, or a book is written by someone? (*without* saying directed and written).

> One of my favourite movies is Indiana Jones **by/from/of** Lucas.
>
> I enjoyed reading The Stranger **by/from/of** Camus.

Comment: "by" is OK for authors, but your first sentence is too vague. You cannot tell written/directed/starred etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you. Do you mean the Lucas one? The context is of course one where I'm talking about books/movies, so to stop repeating myself I stop saying _written/directed_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usual custom dictates that the **author** of a book is the one who *owns* it and the **director** of a movie is the one who *owns* and the choreographer of a dance is the one who *owns** it

> **Lucas'** *Indiana Jones*
>   **Camus'** *The Stranger*
>   **Balanchine's** *The Nutcraker*

in the above, different versions would be referred to by the *owners* name

> Teacher: So class,what did you think of *The Stranger*?
>   Student: Which one?
>
> **Orson Welles'** *The Stranger*
>   **Guillermo Amoedo's** *The Stranger*
>   **Robert Leiberman's** *The Stranger*

are all different films with the same title.

> Which *Nutcracker* are they doing this year?
>
> **Balanchine's** *The Nutcracker*
>   **Petipa's** *The Nutcracker*
>   **San Francisco Ballet's** *The Nutcracker*
>   **Ballet Scotland's** *The Nutcracker*

are different versions of the same dance.

To say that *something* is **by** *someone* might lead to some ambiguity of what's being referred to since movies can be based on a story in a book

> P1: *In Cold Blood* is by Richard Brooks
>   P2: No its not, it's by Truman Capote
>   P1: I was talking about the movie
>   P2: But the book is much better
>
> *In Cold Blood* directed by Richard Brooks based on a story by Truman Capote

has no ambiguity.

In movies there is the added layer of a **screenwriter** who's name might be used if they happen to be famous.

Comment: Great explanation! So only in a _non-ambiguous_ scenario *by* would be ok?

Comment: You can always use **by**, just be ready to explain it. If whom you're talking to took the same classes as you, you both may think in the same way and they might instantly understand what you are referring to.  If you say **Purple Rain** are you talking about the song, the album, or the film? Most people will think of the song if you're in film class it might be more biased towards the film. However, if you say *The Stranger* most people who are Western Literature educated will think Camus.